# jQuery | From jQuery to native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for the way to translate this block of code from jQuery to pure javascript. Is it possible?

```
jQuery(".menu2").each(function(){
       $menu = jQuery(this);          
       $menu.find("li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').filter(".deeper").children("span.separator").addClass("parent");
       $menu.find("li.deeper>a.parent, li.deeper>span.separator").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).parent("li").children("ul").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 300, "jswing");
       });
       $menu.find("li a.parent > span.linker").click(function(){
            if((typeof jQuery(this).parent().attr("href") != 'undefined') && jQuery(this).parent().attr("href") != "#"){
                jQuery(this).parent().unbind('click');
                myLink = jQuery(this).parent().attr("href");
                window.location.href = myLink;
            }
       });        
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Given that jQuery is a package/library that is itself written in JavaScript then the answer to your question is "yes ... it is possible to translate the code to eliminate jQuery calls".  However, it is unclear why you would want to do that?  Also, the act of doing that work for you would not be a "question" on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Posting "implement this for me" questions on SO is strongly discouraged. Please try to do your own research first.

Comment: you can have a look here: [Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Whether it's a good idea or not is debatable, but here...

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".menu2"),function(menu){
  [].forEach.call(menu.getElementsByTagName("li"),function(li) {
    li.__events = li.__events || {};
    if( li.__events.mouseenter) {
      li.removeEventListener('mouseenter',li.__events.mouseenter);
      delete li.__events.mouseenter;
    }
    if( li.__events.mouseleave) {
      li.removeEventListener('mouseleave',li.__events.mouseleave);
      delete li.__events.mouseleave;
    }
    if( li.className.match(/\bdeeper\b/)) {
      [].forEach.call(li.querySelectorAll("span.separator"),function(span) {
        if( !span.className.match(/\bparent\b/)) span.className += " match";
      });
    }
  });
  [].forEach.call(menu.querySelectorAll("li.deeper>a.parent, li.deeper>span.separator"),function(elem) {
    elem.__events = elem.__events || {};
    if( elem.__events.click) {
      elem.removeEventListener('click',elem.__events.click);
      delete elem.__events.click;
    }
    elem.addEventListener('click',elem.__events.click = function(e) {
      [].forEach.call(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul'),function(ul) {
        if( ul.style.height == "auto") ul.style.height = "0px";
        else ul.style.height = "auto";
        // TODO: Implement animation here
      });
      return false;
    },false);
  });
  [].forEach.call(menu.querySelectorAll("li a.parent>span.linker"),function(elem) {
    elem.__events = elem.__events || {};
    if( elem.__events.click) {
      elem.removeEventListener('click',elem.__events.click);
      delete elem.__events.click;
    }
    elem.addEventListener('click',elem.__events.click = function(e) {
      if( this.parentNode.getAttribute("href") != "#") {
        window.location.href = this.parentNode.href;
      }
      return false;
    },false);
  });
});
```

... I think it's fairly obvious why people use jQuery. Of course, I would have my own toolbox to make a lot of this code easier to manage ;)

Comment: @user889349 Please note also that this code uses newer JavaScript features, and therefore will not work in older browsers, whereas the jQuery version will because it has patched in support.

Comment: Where can I find your toolbox?

Comment: @user889349 You can't. I wrote it specifically for my project. It won't work with other projects without significant rewriting, because I made several "bold" optimisations on it.